# Convergence of Puiseux series in an topological algebraically closed field

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

The classical Puiseux theorem states that the field of the Puiseux series over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ $F$ is also an algebraically closed field. Hence for each point of a curve given by a polynomial $f\in F[x,y]$ the polynomial can be written formally as $f(x,y) = A(x)(y-f_1(x))\dots(y-f_k(x))$, where $A,f_1,\dots,f_k$ are formally Puiseux series over $F$. In the complex case, i.e. $F=\mathbb{C}$, it is also known that around this particular point, these Puiseux series converge with a positive radius, i.e. there's a $\delta>0$ such that for all $f_i$ are defined in $\{|x-x_0|<\delta\}$ as a function and for all $y\in\mathbb{C}$, $f(x,y) = A(x)(y-f_1(x))\dots(y-f_k(x))$,  see for instance II§6 of Introduction to Complex Analytic Geometry by S. Lojasiewicz.

Is there any reference for an extension of the convergence part to topological fields? I.e. given an algebraically closed field $F$ with characteristic $0$, which topologies on $F$ would ensure that, in an infinite neighborhood of a point $(x_0,y_0)$ of the curve, the

Comment: In "converge with a positive radius" do you mean $F\subset \Bbb{C}$ as normed fields ? It will hold as well for $F\subset \Bbb{C}_p$ and any algebraically closed characteristic $0$ field with a topology given by a non-archimedian absolute value, due to how Hensel lemma constructs the roots $f_j(x)$.

Comment: @reuns, no. I'm searching for algebraically closed topological fields in which each Puiseux series $f_i$ above can be a function in a neighborhood of a point of the curve, i.e. what topology on this field could guarantee the convergence of $f_i$ in a neighbourhod of a point of the curve.

Comment: Please read your question again, you obviously need some assumptions on $F$ (at least a norm) to make sense to "converges with a positive radius". Then your question is how to relax those assumptions. Also the $f_j(x)$ are Puiseux series in $x-a$ where $(a,b)$ is the point of your curve around which you do the expansion.

Comment: @reuns, thanks for the suggestions. I forgot to mention that I was referring to the complex case.